# Access object info from another method

Tags: java, object

I have a program, but I do not understand how I can access info from one particular object in another method.
This is a minor sample of my program, I want to create this method riders in the same class(called Cyclist). I want to print out the list of riders here, but I do not understand how...

```
public void riders() {
    //System.out.print(c1.getName())
    //this does not work.
    //here I want to print out all the names of the riders, i.e. c1's name, c2's name... cn... 

}



public void abilities() {

    //Pardilla blir til!
    Cyclist c1 = new Cyclist();

    c1.setName("Sergio Pardilla");
    c1.setMountain(75);
    c1.setTimeTrial(60);
    c1.setSprint(60);
    c1.setAge(30);

    System.out.println(c1.getName() + "'s abilities:");
    System.out.println("Mountain - " + c1.getMountain());
    System.out.println("TimeTrial - " + c1.getTimeTrial());
    System.out.println("Sprint - " + c1.getSprint());
    System.out.println("Age - " +c1.getAge());

    }
```

Comment: Pass required object as parameter to `riders` method

Comment: You can't because c1 is a local variable, if you want to access to c1 in other method it must be a field.

Comment: You have to store all riders in an object like a `Collection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no visibility of c1 variable in riders() method.
c1 is declared inside abilities(), and then its local to it, only visible inside.
If you want to use a variable outside this method, you should use a field instead a local variable, or pass it as parameter to rider method.

```
List<Cyclist> cyclists = new ArrayList<>(); // Declared as field

public void riders() {
    for (cyclist : cyclists){
      System.out.print(cyclist.getName())
    }
}



public void abilities() {

//Pardilla blir til!
Cyclist c1 = new Cyclist();

c1.setName("Sergio Pardilla");
c1.setMountain(75);
c1.setTimeTrial(60);
c1.setSprint(60);
c1.setAge(30);

System.out.println(c1.getName() + "'s abilities:");
System.out.println("Mountain - " + c1.getMountain());
System.out.println("TimeTrial - " + c1.getTimeTrial());
System.out.println("Sprint - " + c1.getSprint());
System.out.println("Age - " +c1.getAge());

cyclists.add(c1); //Add cyclist to cyclists list
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate, that makes sense. But why do you declare the Arraylist as "List"?

Comment: @p3ob2lem ArrayList subclasses ArrayList, and a weak declaration is OK if you only need the contract of List, in some Java style guideline sets.

Comment: You always have to find the higher level os abstraction available.I could declared it as Collection, an higher abstraction of List, but this is a race, and you probably need some kind of order.

Comment: Ok so I copy pasted the changes, but still it does not work properly. The riders method that is. Syntax error: insert identifier to complete enhancedforstatementheaderunit. and also I get cannot make a static reference to the non static method getName from the type Cyclist

Answer (score 1):

Cyclist c1 is confined within the scope of the abilities method, which is why you can't access it in the riders() method.

First of all, I would keep an instance-scope ArrayList of Cyclists declared at the top of the class.

```
private ArrayList<Cyclist> cyclists = new ArrayList<Cyclist>();
```

Then, in your abilities method, you should add c1 to the ArrayList cyclists, like

```
cyclists.add(c1);
```

after you've changed c1's settings.  Then, from the riders() method, you can get c1's name with

```
cyclists.get(0).getName();
```

Comment: Why cyclists should be static?

Comment: You're right, OP's methods aren't static - I'll remove the static keyword.  Thanks!

Comment: @p3ob2lem If this answer helped you to your satisfaction, please mark the checkmark at its left to indicate that you would like to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

c1 is defined locally in the abilities() method. Other methods are unable to access it. You either need abilities to return c1 so you can use it in other methods or you can declare a field in that class to store c1.

Answer (score 0):

short : you cannot access objects from a method which are only declared within another method

1) let `riders` accept a `Cyclist` object, and then pass the object.

or

2) make the `Cyclist` class wide accessable :

```
public class XY {
   private Cyclist c1;

   public void riders() {
      // show stuff
   }

   public void abilities() {
      // init stuff
   }

}
```

Furthermore if u want to output all Cyclists, consider using a `List<Cyclist>` which should store each `Cyclist` object.